# How do I extract command's variables?

Tags: lua

I would like to know how to extract the variables passed to a command using Lua.

Let's imagine we have a string like this one:

> [["E:/League of Legends/RADS/projects/league_client/releases/0.0.0.154/deploy/LeagueClientUx.exe" "--release=0.0.0.124" "--rads-product-directory=E:/League of Legends/RADS/solutions/league_client_sln/releases/0.0.0.124/deploy/" "--remoting-auth-token=sometoken" "--respawn-command=LeagueClient.exe" "--respawn-display-name=League of Legends" "--app-port=54584" "--install-directory=E:/League of Legends/" "--app-name=LeagueClient" "--ux-name=LeagueClientUx" "--ux-helper-name=LeagueClientUxHelper" "--log-dir=LeagueClient Logs" "--bugsplat-name=league_client_riotgames_com" "--bugsplat-platform-id=EUW1" "--app-log-file-path=E:/League of Legends/Logs/LeagueClient Logs/2018-07-10T15-32-34_35052_LeagueClient.log" "--app-pid=35052" "--no-proxy-server"]]

How would I successfully extract for example, port and app-pid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string.gmatch`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch)

```
local str = [["E:/League of Legends/RADS/projects/league_client/releases/0.0.0.154/deploy/LeagueClientUx.exe" "--release=0.0.0.124" "--rads-product-directory=E:/League of Legends/RADS/solutions/league_client_sln/releases/0.0.0.124/deploy/" "--remoting-auth-token=sometoken" "--respawn-command=LeagueClient.exe" "--respawn-display-name=League of Legends" "--app-port=54584" "--install-directory=E:/League of Legends/" "--app-name=LeagueClient" "--ux-name=LeagueClientUx" "--ux-helper-name=LeagueClientUxHelper" "--log-dir=LeagueClient Logs" "--bugsplat-name=league_client_riotgames_com" "--bugsplat-platform-id=EUW1" "--app-log-file-path=E:/League of Legends/Logs/LeagueClient Logs/2018-07-10T15-32-34_35052_LeagueClient.log" "--app-pid=35052" "--no-proxy-server"]]

for k,v in string.gmatch(str, "\"%-%-([^=]+)=([^\"]+)") do
  print(string.format("%s=%s", k, v))
end
```

---

```
local str = [["E:/League of Legends/RADS/projects/league_client/releases/0.0.0.154/deploy/LeagueClientUx.exe" "--release=0.0.0.124" "--rads-product-directory=E:/League of Legends/RADS/solutions/league_client_sln/releases/0.0.0.124/deploy/" "--remoting-auth-token=sometoken" "--respawn-command=LeagueClient.exe" "--respawn-display-name=League of Legends" "--app-port=54584" "--install-directory=E:/League of Legends/" "--app-name=LeagueClient" "--ux-name=LeagueClientUx" "--ux-helper-name=LeagueClientUxHelper" "--log-dir=LeagueClient Logs" "--bugsplat-name=league_client_riotgames_com" "--bugsplat-platform-id=EUW1" "--app-log-file-path=E:/League of Legends/Logs/LeagueClient Logs/2018-07-10T15-32-34_35052_LeagueClient.log" "--app-pid=35052" "--no-proxy-server"]]

local params = {}
for k,v in string.gmatch(str, "\"%-%-([^=]+)=([^\"]+)") do
  params[k] = v
end

print(params["app-pid"])
print(params["app-port"])
```

Outputs:

```
release=0.0.0.124
rads-product-directory=E:/League of Legends/RADS/solutions/league_client_sln/releases/0.0.0.124/deploy/
remoting-auth-token=sometoken
respawn-command=LeagueClient.exe
respawn-display-name=League of Legends
app-port=54584
install-directory=E:/League of Legends/
app-name=LeagueClient
ux-name=LeagueClientUx
ux-helper-name=LeagueClientUxHelper
log-dir=LeagueClient Logs
bugsplat-name=league_client_riotgames_com
bugsplat-platform-id=EUW1
app-log-file-path=E:/League of Legends/Logs/LeagueClient Logs/2018-07-10T15-32-34_35052_LeagueClient.log
app-pid=35052
```

http://rextester.com/JEYCF1205

Also, see [Lua Patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) on how to create your own patterns. It's pretty much like regular expressions.